# Parents of old age and children of 'disability'

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, children-parenting

While working I saw an old lady being aided by her daughter and grandson. I stood out of respect.

Then it hit me. My last job before lunch was a mother of a son who was a quaddraplegic.

I know the works of Rabbi Nachman in Sefer hamiddot would address something like this but I haven't found an entry.

So my question is if anyone has ever explained why some parents must be cared for by children in childhood or old age and explained the reason why parents who must care for their child/ren like down syndrome and the likes? Another was children who grow up quicker to care for adults (depression, etc.).

Comment: Can you review the second paragraph? What hit you? And what does "My last job before lunch was a mother of a son who was a quaddraplegic." mean? Is your question "Why is God doing this to these people?" Or something else?